# tabcontrol page not updated

Tags: tabcontrol, selectedindexchanged

In my winfom program I have a function that change the tabpage when I hit a key.

On tabcontrol indexchanged I check for some parametre and if they are not correct I change the tabpage to the first tab.

If I click on the page with the mouse the tabpage changed to the first tab with the correct content.

If I click a key and run this code "tcOrdre.SelectedTab = tpOrdre;" it changes the tab back to the first but still showing the content of the selected one.

In SelectedIndexChanged is use this code:

MessageBox.Show("Der skal vælges en ordre først"); // Show a messagebox

tcOrdre.SelectedTab = tpOrdreListe;                // change tap to first

If I use the mouse then SelectIndexChanged get called when I run:

tcOrdre.SelectedTab = tpOrdreListe;                // change tap to first

the SelectedIndexChanged function is called again and the content is okay.

But if I use the key to change index the SelectedIndexChanged does not get called Again and the content never change. Only the tab in the top change to the first one.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
All I have to do is call this line.

this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tcOrdre.SelectTab(0)));

and not tcOrdre.SelectedTab = tpOrdreListe;

And everything Works fine.